# Why is this IPS plugin giving me an registration error?

Tags: xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin name="One IP One Account" version_long="10000" version_human="1.0.0" author="Faqole" website="https://www.generalcartalk.com" update_check="">
    <hooks>
        <hook type="C" class="\IPS\core\modules\front\system\register" filename="oneiponeaccount">
            <![CDATA[//<?php

/* To prevent PHP errors (extending class does not exist) revealing path */
if ( !defined( '\IPS\SUITE_UNIQUE_KEY' ) )
{
    exit;
}

class hook702 extends _HOOK_CLASS_
{
    /**
     * Normal registration form
     *
     * @return \IPS\Form
     */
    protected function _registrationForm()
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                try
                {
                     $ips = \IPS\Db::i()->select( '*', 'core_members', array( 'ip_address=?',  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) );
                }
                     catch( \UnderflowException $e )
               {

               }

               $results = count( $ips );
               if (!empty($results))
               {
                   $sameIpErrorMessage = \IPS\Member::loggedIn()->language()->addToStack('same_ip_error_message', FALSE, array( 'sprintf' => array(  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ) );
                   \IPS\Output::i()->error( $sameIpErrorMessage, 'OneIpOneAccount', 403, '' );
               }

               return parent::_registrationForm( );
            }
            catch ( \RuntimeException $e )
            {
                if ( method_exists( get_parent_class(), __FUNCTION__ ) )
                {
                    return call_user_func_array( 'parent::' . __FUNCTION__, func_get_args() );
                }
                else
                {
                    throw $e;
                }
            }
        }
        catch ( \RuntimeException $e )
        {
            if ( method_exists( get_parent_class(), __FUNCTION__ ) )
            {
                return call_user_func_array( 'parent::' . __FUNCTION__, func_get_args() );
            }
            else
            {
                throw $e;
            }
        }
    }
}
]]>
        </hook>
    </hooks>
    <htmlFiles/>
    <cssFiles/>
    <jsFiles/>
    <resourcesFiles/>
    <lang>
        <word key="same_ip_error_message" js="0">According to our database records there is already an account registered from this ip: %s.</word>
    </lang>
    <versions/>
</plugin>
```

This is the code for a **IPS** plugin that allow only one account to be register on 1 IP. The plugin works fine, it blocks you from creating another account on same IP. But it also block the whole registeration site. It shows the following error.
[This is the error it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i12si.jpg)

I am not sure what the error is, help will be appreciated.